# IDEA: how to move Java class across modules

Tags: java, maven

Moving class across Maven Modules is a real pain. For two reasons:

- you have to update maven deps;
- your imports got broken.

I remediate those two by:

1. Manually updating all broken deps.
2. Find/replace import text project-wide.

Doesn't seem convenient (and it is NOT) and doesn't seem like a dev-process in year 2015. Is there a way to move Java class across Maven modules with less trouble?

Comment: Carelessly adding deps to another module might have unforeseen consequences and interfere with your overall architecture. So I think it's ok for it to be some work. Then you might think about it again.

Answer (score 2):

I am using IntelliJ, and both steps can be automatically by the IDE, in reverse order.

**First, for step 2** - *Fix the imports*:

Just drag-and-drop the class from it's source to the destination package in another maven module, and you'll get the "Move" options window.

Ensure `To package` is correct and `Target destination directory` is a valid source root (click `Refactor`).

The imports wherever the class is used should be updated.

**Now, for step 1** - *Update the maven deps*

This step needs to be repeated in each maven module where the class is used.

Go to a class in a module which makes use of the class but does not have the property maven dependency, find a usage of the class name which is marked **red**.

Use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to pop up the list of fixes and select the last option: **Add Maven dependency...** and select the maven module the class was moved to.

Alternatively you can update the pom.xml manually.

Lastly, Do a full maven build.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy in eclipse just drag and drop it to the other maven module and it will ask u to update all the references just click ok and its done

[image]

Comment: No objections from using Eclipse, but I, personally, use IDEA and it's not smart to change horses in midstream.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, when tried to relocate class from one module to another.
You need to install your changes to local repository using maven:

```
mvn clean install
```

and than your changes will be visible for another modules.